# Trying to set min & max time date in jquery datepicker in two inputs

Tags: javascript, html

So I am working on a project for my classes and I had to set minimum and maximum date for two inputs. First one is being set from now to 12 months from now, and the other was meant to be set from date which was picked in the first input field to 12 months from now.

```
<p>From: <input type="text" id="dateFrom"></p>
<p>To: <input type="text" id="dateTo"></p>
```

this is my JS

```
    var chosenDate = document.getElementById("dateFrom").value;
$( function() {
          $("#dateFrom").datepicker({
          dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          maxDate: '12M',
          minDate: '0',
            });
        })

      $( function() {
          $("#dateTo").datepicker({
          dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          maxDate: '12M',
          minDate: chosenDate,
            });
        })
```

On the preview in a browser it works only for last session. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use change event on #dateFrom, so whenever the value of the input is changed,the minDate property of the datepicker event get the current input value
of #dateFrom

```
$("#dateFrom").change(() => {
$("#dateTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", chosenDate.value);
});
```

the final code should be like this:

```
var chosenDate = document.getElementById("dateFrom");
$(function() {
  $("#dateFrom").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: "12M",
    minDate: "0"
  });
});
$(function() {
  $("#dateTo").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: "12M",
    minDate: chosenDate.value
  });
  $("#dateFrom").change(() => {
    $("#dateTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", chosenDate.value);
  });
});
```

notice the chosenDate variable is now just the element not the value of the element

Comment: Alright, can you tell me where to put it in this scenario? Because, when I just add it under variables, the input goes disabled.

Comment: I've checked this on codepen, and it is working beautifully, for which I am really grateful, but unfortunatelly not in my project. I'll mention, that I've hooked jquery-1.12.4.js and 1.12.1/jquery-ui.js in the <head> section of my HTML and ID's on inputs are still the same. They seem to be just text input fields. Any advice?

Comment: do you use an external js file? if yes, make sure that your <script>  src attribute be the same as your js file name.